# FFprobe reports Invalid sample_count on very large .mov file

Tags: video, large-files, mov, ffprobe, mediainfo

I have a 1.1TB ProRes 422 MOV file (a bit more than 24 hours of recording).

When running `ffprobe -v error -print_format xml -select_streams v:0 -show_format -show_streams "Metadata Error.mov"` I get the following:

```
<ffprobe>
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000000000709520] Invalid sample_count=-118755256
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000000000709520] error reading header
Metadata Error.mov: Invalid data found when processing input
</ffprobe>
```

But if I run `mediainfo`, I get correct information:

```
General
Complete name                            : Metadata Error.mov
Format                                   : YSDO
Codec ID                                 : YSDO (qt  /YSDO)
File size                                : 1.10 TiB
Duration                                 : 24 h 10 min
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 111 Mb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-09-24 23:48:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-09-26 09:23:29
Writing library                          : mtrx

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : ProRes
Format version                           : Version 0
Format profile                           : 422
Codec ID                                 : apcn
Duration                                 : 24 h 10 min
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 101 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Clean aperture width                     : 1 888 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Clean aperture height                    : 1 062 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Clean aperture display aspect ratio      : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 (29970/1000) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Scan type                                : Interlaced
Scan type, store method                  : Interleaved fields
Scan order                               : Top Field First
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 1.633
Stream size                              : 1.00 TiB (92%)
Writing library                          : apm0
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-09-24 23:48:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-09-26 09:23:29
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
matrix_coefficients_Original             : BT.709

Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : in24
Duration                                 : 24 h 10 min
Source duration                          : 24 h 10 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 152 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Stream size                              : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Source stream size                       : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-09-24 23:48:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-09-26 09:23:29
mdhd_Duration                            : 66187116

Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : in24
Duration                                 : 24 h 10 min
Source duration                          : 24 h 10 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 152 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Stream size                              : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Source stream size                       : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-09-24 23:48:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-09-26 09:23:29
mdhd_Duration                            : 66187116

Audio #3
ID                                       : 4
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : in24
Duration                                 : 24 h 10 min
Source duration                          : 24 h 10 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 152 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Stream size                              : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Source stream size                       : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-09-24 23:48:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-09-26 09:23:29
mdhd_Duration                            : 66187116

Audio #4
ID                                       : 5
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : in24
Duration                                 : 24 h 10 min
Source duration                          : 24 h 10 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 152 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Stream size                              : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Source stream size                       : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-09-24 23:48:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-09-26 09:23:29
mdhd_Duration                            : 66187116

Audio #5
ID                                       : 6
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : in24
Duration                                 : 24 h 10 min
Source duration                          : 24 h 10 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 152 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Stream size                              : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Source stream size                       : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-09-24 23:48:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-09-26 09:23:29
mdhd_Duration                            : 66187116

Audio #6
ID                                       : 7
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : in24
Duration                                 : 24 h 10 min
Source duration                          : 24 h 10 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 152 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Stream size                              : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Source stream size                       : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-09-24 23:48:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-09-26 09:23:29
mdhd_Duration                            : 66187116

Audio #7
ID                                       : 8
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : in24
Duration                                 : 24 h 10 min
Source duration                          : 24 h 10 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 152 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Stream size                              : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Source stream size                       : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-09-24 23:48:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-09-26 09:23:29
mdhd_Duration                            : 66187116

Audio #8
ID                                       : 9
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : in24
Duration                                 : 24 h 10 min
Source duration                          : 24 h 10 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 152 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Stream size                              : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Source stream size                       : 11.7 GiB (1%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-09-24 23:48:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-09-26 09:23:29
mdhd_Duration                            : 66187116
```

Comment: For future readers, best to answer it yourself with a reference to your applied patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was a bug in FFmpeg. Thank God it was an easy fix!

[Patch](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=1015982f45d832ee926a81460121673a97292333)